# Concatenation of the same bits

Tags: vhdl

I am writing a simple vga controller and I find myself repeating the same pattern again and again. How I can avoid this.

```
red_out <= zero(x-106,y-63)&zero(x-106,y-63)&zero(x-106,y63)&zero(x-106,y-63);
green_out <= zero(x-106,y-63)&zero(x-106,y-63)&zero(x-106,y-63)&zero(x-106,y-63);
blue_out <= zero(x-106,y-63)&zero(x-106,y-63)&zero(x-106,y-63)&zero(x-106,y-63);
```

Maybe a command that will help me avoid the repetition?

Comment: Are you repeating the whole block you posted or are you referring only to the expression `zero(x-106,y-63)&zero(x-106,y-63)&zero(x-106,y63)&zero(x-106,y-63)`?

Comment: @simon Both of them. If I can get rid of something it would be a great improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To replace the expression `zero(x-106,y-63)&zero(x-106,y-63)&zero(x-106,y63)&zero(x-106,y-63)`, use a **function**. The code would then look something like `red_out<=f(zero, x, y);` etc.
- To replace all three statements, use a **procedure**. The code would then look something like `p(red_out, green_out, blue_out, zero, x, y)`.

Check http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/design.html for the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If your vectors receive a copy a the same single bit then the following code would do it, and would be simpler than resorting to functions:

```
red_out   <= (others => zero(x-106,y-63));
green_out <= (others => zero(x-106,y-63));
blue_out  <= (others => zero(x-106,y-63));
```

or even

```
my_bit    <= zero(x-106,y-63);
red_out   <= (others => my_bit);
green_out <= (others => my_bit);
blue_out  <= (others => my_bit);
```